# Pros and cons with allowing black raspberry plants to spread?

Tags: raspberries, invasive

Around 8 years ago, we planted a decent sized patch of black raspberries.  I've since stopped maintaining it (no spraying, weeding...anything).  Now years later, I'm seeing black raspberry vines coming up other places on my property up to 500ft away.

I know the question of whether or not I "want" them on my property is too subjective, so my question is, are they considered invasive in NW Ohio?  Will they overtake other plants, trees...etc? Are there other problems associated with just letting them grow wild wherever they may pop up?

Comment: They are not on the official list: https://agri.ohio.gov/divisions/plant-health/invasive-pests/invasive-plants